# Clickonce application generates SmartScreen warning though it's digitally signed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce, publish

My ClickOnce installer generates a SmartScreen warning. The executable is signed by a Microsoft Authenticode valid certificate though. The project is generated using Visual Studio 2012 (it's a C# Console Project, containing two DLL, one for JSON and another for PKCS11Interop).

Here is the signing configuration of Visual Studio :

[image: Visual Studio Signing configuration]

I also added this target after compile in order to digitally sign the executable contained into the installer :

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe&quot; sign /f &quot;$(ProjectDir)CertificatCodeSigning.pfx&quot; /p mypassword /v &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

When I take a look at the setup.exe generated, I have this :

[image]

But when I take a look at the executable contained into the setup.exe, I have a sha1 digest instead of a sha256 :

[image]

When I execute the setup.exe from a Windows 8/8.1, I still get a SmartScreen warning. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,